# Count continuously occurring values for each group pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to count the number of occurrences of the same event that occurs continuously. Sorry I couldnt frame my question properly, let me give you an example

```
id  date    L1    L2
1   1/8     A     B
1   2/8     B     C
1   3/8     B     A
2   2/8     A     B
2   3/8     B     A
2   4/8     A     B
3   5/8     A     B
3   6/8     B     A
3   7/8     B     C
3   8/8     C     A
3   8/8     A     B
```

My resultant dataframe looks like below:

```
id  L1   L2  count
2   A    B   3
3   A    B   2
```

id 1 is not counted because it did not occur on a continuous basis, and id 3 is not counted as 3 because B and C came in the middle. Any subsequent event after that is considered a loop again

Answer (score 1):

Solved using the below tech

```
df.sort_values(by=['id','date'], inplace=True)
df['groupId'] = df['L2'].eq(df.groupby('id')['L1']).shift(1).groupby(['id']).cumsum()
```

This groupID will hold consecutive events